# Definition of marked curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to learn algebraic geometry but cannot find a definition for the term "marked curve" or "curve with marked points". I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_of_algebraic_curves) wiki page. There's a section relating to moduli on marked curves.

Comment: Thank you. But (to me) that still does not explain what a marked curve is?

Comment: It is a curve with marked points ... marked points are just discrete points (varieties of genus 0)

Comment: I think @DonThousand means that points are varieties of dimension $0$. Anyway, a marked curve is an ordered pair $(C,x)$, where $x \in C$. So if $x\neq y$ are distinct points on $C$, as marked curves we have $(C,x)\neq (C,y)$. And while these two pairs are necessarily not equal, they are isomorphic as marked curves precisely when there is an automorphism $f:C\to C$ with $f(x) = y$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Yea it's been a while since I've done AG, I goofed up some of the terminology. Point is, it is quite similar to the notion of pointed spaces in topology.